# Setting up DNS server to accept dynamic updates without FQDN

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2008-r2, dynamic-dns, fqdn

I have set up a *Win2k8 R2* server with the DNS role enabled. I had to add the server to a fictional workgroup/domain called dns.com so as to be able to use it as a primary DNS server to my network of one computer. Now the problem is that everytime I try to add a resource record for just *hostname*, using *nsupdate* I get the response: *could not find enclosing zone*

As soon as I change the hostname to *hostname.dns.com* it successfully updates. Is there any way to bypass this FQDN requirement either at the DNS server side or the client side?

I am using the following:

```
$ cat /tmp/dns1
server 10.106.27.241
update delete hostname a
update add hostname 86400 a 10.106.145.1
send
$ nsupdate -v /tmp/dns1
could not find enclosing zone
$ cat /tmp/dns2
server 10.106.27.241
update delete hostname.dns.com a
update add hostname.dns.com 86400 a 10.106.145.1
send
$ nsupdate -v /tmp/dns2
$
```

Comment: Is it a workgroup or a domain? They're two different things. If it's a domain, is the DNS zone AD-integrated?

Comment: Its a domain and I named the zone as dns.com as well. Yes it is AD-integrated.

Comment: The server will only update client hostnames for zones that it's an authority for. Create the zone your host will be in, (ie zone2.local), set all the relevant settings regarding dynamic updates (secure or insecure) from clients, then your client will be able to send through an accepted dynamic update.

Comment: Is there any way to configure the DNS server to accept any hostname say "foobar" and treat it as foobar.domain.com